# precision score warnings results in score =0 sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I am using precision_score in sklearn to evaluate the result of the outlier detection algorithm.
I trained with one class only and predict on unseen data. So the label for the one class is just 0 all the way.

I have found the following:

[image]

There are two columns, truth and predicted.
(I used the label encoder to beautify the number, in Local Outlier Factor, it output 1 for inlier and -1 for the outlier, I use label encoder to encode them into 0s and 1s, same for the truth)

[image]

However, the algorithm returns that my accuracy is 1, but precision is 0. It can be clearly seen that the predicted match with the truth completely. I would expect to get scores of 1s for both parameters. It comes with the below warning:

[image]

What should I do or any links I should be reading to mitigate this issue.

Comment: The documentation explains that with only two classes, it treats it as a binary problem. Precision is about true positives (guessing 1 when the answer is 1). You don’t have any—just true negatives (guessing 0 when the answer is 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation explains that with only two classes, it treats it as a binary problem. Precision is about true positives (guessing 1 when the answer is 1). You don’t have any—just true negatives (guessing 0 when the answer is 0).

If you’re really unhappy with that outcome, you can use the zero_division argument:

```
precision_score(truth, predicted, zero_division=1)
```

That way, you’ll get the 1 you want.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful analogy. Now i get it, since my results are all 0s, precision is not accurate here. I would like to know what can I do to get the False Positive scores in the classification problem like mine

Comment: Well that’s another question. If you want it, you can use the pos_lab argument to the precision function. Set it to 0 instead of its default (1).